# Setting a ProgressBar to VISIBLE on click in android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make my ProgressBar turn VISIBLE when the LogIn button is clicked.  Here's my XML for the Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtView_UserName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/login_username_hint">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtView_Password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView_UserName"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:hint="@string/login_password_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_LogIn"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtView_UserName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView_Password"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:onClick="logIn"
    android:text="@string/login_button" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_RememberPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtView_Password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_Login"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/remember_my_password" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_LogMeInAutomatically"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkbox_RememberPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_RememberPassword"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
    android:text="@string/log_me_in_automatically" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar_LogIn"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkbox_LogMeInAutomatically"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtView_Version"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="@string/version_number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is where I am trying to change it to VISIBLE in the code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//Get Views and Buttons
 EditText txt_Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_UserName);
 EditText txt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtView_Password);
 Button btn_LogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_LogIn);
 CheckBox chkbox_RememberMyPassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_RememberPassword);
 CheckBox chkbox_LogMeInAutomatically = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_LogMeInAutomatically);
 ProgressBar progressbar_LogIn = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_LogIn);    

public void logIn() {
    progressbar_LogIn.setVisibility(0);
}

}
```

The program is crashing without rendering my Activity's Views.  Any ideas?

Comment: How is it crashing? Is there a logcat error we can use?

Comment: I'm seeing null pointer exceptions, but it's not saying where really.

Comment: Are you getting the views and buttons in onCreateView?

Comment: What do you mean OnCreateView?

Comment: You should be setting up all the graphical elements when the view is created for the activity. Make sure to override onCreateView. I edited my answer some more to show that in code.

Comment: Is that different from the OnCreate method (see code above)?

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling its because you have an onClick for login, but login doesn't take a view parameter. Try setting the onclick for the button programmatically, instead of using the xml.

Edit: Try changing

```
public void logIn() {
progressbar_LogIn.setVisibility(0);
```

}

to

```
public void logIn(View v) {
progressbar_LogIn.setVisibility(0);
```

}

or to set it programatically

```
btn_LogIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //CODE GOES HERE
        }
    });
```

Further Edit:

Also noticed that theres no sign of an onCreateView so make sure that all that view code is inside of, or atleast inside of onCreate:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Still crashed.  How would I set the onClick for the button programatically?

Comment: Edited to add programatically. If you add it that way, make sure to remove the old onClick in the XML aswell

Comment: Yes it is. OnCreate is when the activity is created, onCreateView is when the view for the activity is created. You might want to check out some starter android tutorials, there are some good ones on the android main site. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: When the Activity is created, it inflates the Activity's XML layout sheet with all the views, though doesn't it?  Why would I need both?  I'm not trying to recreate new views, just access the ones already in the XML layout page.

Comment: onCreateView is part of onCreate, so when you call the super you are calling the basic onCreateView aswell. Technically you don't need to do the work in onCreateview specifically, but to my knowlege it is at least good practice to do it in onCreate. Just an aside though really. Did you get the program working?